# Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined with date

Tags: javascript

Good morning everybody!

I have a problem with javascript. I'm using cases with different days per month. Until December I don't have issues, but when January start (today, firs day of the school) the code doesn't show my schedule and the console display this errors:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined
    at cambiar_imagen (English1.html:386)
    at onload (English1.html:396)**

I was thinking that maybe is the date format, beause of this I have an alert with my variable "dia", this variable content the current date.

This is my code:

Tablet

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function cambiar_imagen (){
        var hoy = new Date();
        var hora = hoy.toLocaleTimeString();
        var day = hoy.getDate();
        var month = hoy.getMonth()+1;
        var year = hoy.getFullYear();
        var dia = (day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
        switch(dia) {
            //A DAY

                //october
                case "18/10/2017":  case "20/10/2017":  case "24/10/2017":  case "26/10/2017":

                //november
                case "6/11/2017":   case "8/11/2017":   case "10/11/2017":  case "14/11/2017":  case "16/11/2017":  case "20/11/2017":  case "22/11/2017":
                case "24/11/2017":  case "28/11/2017":  case "30/11/2017":

                //december
                case "4/12/2017":   case "7/12/2017":   case "12/12/2017":  case "14/12/2017":  case "18/12/2017":  case "20/12/2017":

                //january
                case "8/1/2017":    case "10/1/2017":   case "12/1/2017":   case "16/1/2017":   case "19/1/2017":   case "23/1/2017":   case "25/1/2017":
                case "29/1/2017":   case "31/1/2017":

                //february
                case "2/2/2017":    case "6/2/2017":    case "8/2/2017":    case "19/2/2017":   case "21/2/2017":   case "23/2/2017":   case "27/2/2017":

                //march
                case "2/3/2017":    case "6/3/2017":    case "8/3/2017":    case "12/3/2017":   case "14/3/2017":   case "16/3/2017":   case "20/3/2017":
                case "22/3/2017":

                //april
                case "3/4/2017":    case "5/4/2017":    case "9/4/2017":    case "11/4/2017":   case "13/4/2017":   case "17/4/2017":   case "19/4/2017":
                case "23/4/2017":   case "25/4/2017":   case "27/4/2017":

                //may
                case "2/5/2017":    case "4/5/2017":    case "8/5/2017":    case "10/5/2017":   case "14/5/2017":   case "16/5/2017":   case "18/5/2017":
                case "22/5/2017":   case "24/5/2017":   case "28/5/2017":   case "30/5/2017":

                //june
                case "1/6/2017":    case "5/6/2017":    case "7/6/2017":    case "11/6/2017":   case "13/6/2017":   case "15/6/2017":   case "19/6/2017":

                var hoy = new Date();
                var hora = hoy.toLocaleTimeString();
                var pr = [
                    ['Period 1 (08:30 - 09:45): Ms. Liz Edwards - Social Studies Psychology 11'],
                    ['Period 2 (10:00 - 11:15): Ms. Liz Edwards - English 9A'],
                    ['Period 3 (12:45 - 14:00): Mr. Joe Brogan - Social Studies 11 World History'],
                    ['Period 4 (14:15 - 15:30): Ms. Liz Edwards - English 11 Language & Literature'],
                    ['Enrichment (15:30 - 16:00): Mr. Toni Bauça - Homework Club 7+8'],
                    ['Homeroom PM (16:45 - 17:30): David Pringuer - Homeroom 10 (T)']
                            ];

                    //First Period
                    if
                        (hora > "8:30:00 AM" && hora <= "9:45:00 AM") {

                            text = "First Period - A Day";
                            text2 = "08:30 - 09:45";
                            text3 = "Social Studies Psychology 11";
                            text4 = "Ms. Liz Edwards";
                            text5 = "Next Periods"+"<br>"+"<br>";
                            pr = (pr[1][0])+"<br>"+"<br>"+(pr[2][0])+"<br>"+"<br>"+(pr[3][0]);
                            }
```

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: defined text variable?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats going on with all that case stuff, but looks like simply you didn't declare the "text" variable ( or any of the proceeding text variables ) so when the if block runs it throws the error.

try adding the `var` declaration

```
var text = "First Period - A Day";
var text2 = "08:30 - 09:45";
... etc
```

Comment: I've have it declared at the bottom of the code like: document.getElementById("period").innerHTML = text
   
And I don't think is that, beacuse until December is working, the problem is in Januaary and next months. Last year works properly...